# Mobile (bluetooth) connection to wiimote/controller

Tags: android, ios, mobile, windows-phone-8, bluetooth

Looking to make a game for cross-platform mobile game.
(Android, iOS, Win8)

Playing with a controller is a pretty important feature.  Bluetooth connecting with a Wiimote works, but there are a few other bluetooth controllers I'd like to support as well.  I can do this on a PC, because the bluetooth serial/connection is solvable.

Ideally, it'd be write-once.

Maybe a plugin for Unity3d?  Maybe some other engine?
I'm willing to use pretty much any engine that lets me write custom shaders.

At this point, trying to find examples of programs that can successfully connect, even to the wiimote, using bluetooth on a non-rooted android device is not going well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [wiimote plugin for unity](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UniWii). I have never used it, so I can´t tell you how much customization it needed to make it work with Android, ios and wp8. I guess you could get some help from the unity community but nevertheless this would be something for experineced unity users.

At least for WP8 I know about a [bluetooth api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), which may be used to connect to the wiimote, while you need to write most of the logical mapping by yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, that plugin seems to jump into native code.  So while it's useful for Win8/OSX it falls down on mobile (correct me if I'm making a horrible assumption).

The logical mapping is less scary, in no small part because that will allow multiple controllers to be used.  Is it possible to access the WP8 bluetooth API (and Android bluetooth API) from Unity?

Comment: I am not sure about the API access, as I have never done it myself before. There is a thread about it at this page: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/224161/how-do-i-implement-a-third-party-api-into-unity.html Maybe this would get you started